# The cloud panel doesn't into directory in django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I write cloud panel write python/django. My problem is, urls.py doesn't access next forward directory. I use apache. when it is go to next forward, this page is showing:

https://postimg.org/image/b1t9s26b9/

my urls.py inside:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$','explorer.views.home',name='home'),
    url(r'^servers/$','explorer.views.servers'),
    url(r'^addserver/$','explorer.views.addserver'),
    url(r'^removeserver/$','explorer.views.removeserver'),
    url(r'^manage/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\w]+)/$','manager.views.filemanager'),
    url(r'^navback/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/$','manager.views.navbackward'),
    url(r'^naviforward(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/(?P<dir>[\w]+)/$','manager.views.navforward'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/(?P<file>[\.\w]+)$','manager.views.editdata'),
    url(r'^saveandsend/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/(?P<file>[\.\w]+)$','manager.views.senddata'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/$','manager.views.uploadfile'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/(?P<file>[\.\w]+)$','manager.views.deletefile'),

]
```

my views.py inside:

https://postimg.org/image/s2c60qr2d/

views.py inside for ssh connection and sftp connection :

https://postimg.org/image/635rdjhxx/

my routing to html file inside:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {% if path != orginalpath %}
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/navback/{{ server }}/{{ modpath }}/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" style="color: #ac2925;height: 30px"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% for d in dirs %}
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="color: #eea236"></span>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/naviforward/{{ server }}/{{ modpath }}{{ d }}/">{{ d }}</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}
     </div>
```

if you're access to project and image you can be look in link:

https://postimg.org/gallery/3iakj1t7a/

https://gitlab.com/rection/Cloud-Panel-Django.git

How to be solution my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^naviforward(?P<server>[\w]+)/(?P<path>[\*\w]+)/(?P<dir>[\w]+)/$','manager.views.navforward')
```

`naviforward/<server>matched/<path>matched/<dir>not matched/`

`naviforward/DigitalOcean/*root*docker-bench-security/`

Your regex does have 3 different match groups yet only 2 part is given; and I also believe that `url()` function takes a regex and a callable rather than a regex and a string.

Comment: i change to html file : https://postimg.org/image/vi8vnzg8l/ and the result is unchanged  : https://postimg.org/image/qjld9ix11/

Comment: Even though you changed your html your link is still the same.

Comment: you say 'Your regex does have 3 different match groups yet only 2 part is given; and I also believe that url() function takes a regex and a callable rather than a regex and a string. ' Did you show your source?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) is the docs for it; requires a callable not a string `url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)` And your url indeed only has 2 parts rather than 3 as in your regex, I don't see why you are confused.

Comment: can you change on gitlab https://gitlab.com/rection/Cloud-Panel-Django.git . I could not understand you.